# Limite, ou capacidade de um Vetor

Tags: c, vector

Imaginem que se pede "quando a capacidade chega ao limite deverá avisar o utilizador"
Tenho um vetor de inteiros com 15 posições, e o utilizador vai inserir valores lá para dentro, o objetivo é avisar quando chegar ao final, como?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 15

int lerVectorDeInteiros(int *);
void mostrarVetor(int *);
void inicializarVetor(int *);

int main()
{
    int vetor[MAX];
    int quantidadeElementos = 0;

    inicializarVetor(vetor);

    quantidadeElementos =lerVectorDeInteiros(vetor);
    printf("A quantidade de elementos que foram inseridos no vetor sao %d\n", quantidadeElementos);

    mostrarVetor(vetor);

    return 0;
}

void inicializarVetor(int vetor[MAX]){
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        vetor[i] = 0;
    }

}

int lerVectorDeInteiros(int vetor[MAX]){
    int i;
    int temp = 0;
    int contador = 0;
    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        printf("Insire o valor da posicao %d do vetor: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &temp);
        if(temp > 99 && temp < 501){
            vetor[i] = temp;
            contador++;
        }
    }
    return contador;
}

void mostrarVetor(int vetor[MAX]){
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<MAX; i++){
        printf("O valor da posicao %d e: %d\n", i+1, vetor[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: "quando a capacidade chega ao limite deverá avisar o utilizador" - Se está a ler a quantidade correspondente ao tamanho então nunca irá ler mais que a quantidade. Por isso avisar quando chega ao fim não faz sentido, a menos de talvez colocar um `printf` depois do `for` de leitura para indicar que já leu tudo. Para mim não ficou muito claro o que pretende fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Cria um laço com while(com contador é claro) e ao final do laço adicione uma condição if(se for a posição final)...e da o aviso com printf();

Comment: Boa tarde Mauricio, como vejo, ou "verifico" se é ou não a posição final?

Comment: Sim jovem. Limite= última posição... faz com while... adiciona um contador e poem um if o contador for igual a pos final

Answer (score 0):

Basta colocar um `printf()` avisando que chegou ao limite depois do `for` que esta na sua função `int lerVectorDeInteiros(int vetor[MAX])`, pois sempre quando ele chegar ao final daquele `for`, ou melhor sempre quando ele sair do loop daquele `for`, ele estará no final do vetor, ou seja, no seu limite.

Mas como fazer para checar se está mesmo de fato ou não no final, bom basta pensar na seguinte lógica, "se está no limite, imprime o aviso", tá para fazer isso basta fazer um `if`, neste caso você tem que pensar no seguinte, qual variável representa o limite do vetor?, se você pensar um pouco reparará que é a variável `MAX`, pois ela representa o valor máximo de dados que o vetor suporta, mas não apenas isso, `MAX - 1` representa a ultima posição do vetor, ou seja, para verificar se está ou não no limite faça um `if` onde você compara a posição atual do seu vetor com a ultima, se ele estiver na ultima quer dizer que seu vetor chegou ao limite, nessa altura do campeonato você já deve saber que a variável que representa a posição atual do seu vetor no caso daquele `for` é o `i`, então só basta compara-lo.

Para fazer comparações em `if` existem varias maneiras, para checar se X é maior que Y, basta fazer o seguinte `if ( X > Y )`, para checar se é menor, `if ( X < Y )`, maior ou igual, `if ( X >= Y )`, menor ou igual, `if ( X <= Y )`, verificar se é igual `if ( X == Y )`, aqui você deve tomar cuidado, lembre-se sempre que dois iguais é uma comparação de igualdade, e um é atribuição de valor.

Bom são basicamente estes os operadores de comparação, se eu não esqueci de nenhum, de qualquer forma então o seu `if` ficaria de tal forma `if ( i == MAX - 1 )`, e caso isto seja verdadeiro dai você imprimirá o seu aviso.

Espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa é só perguntar, boa sorte com os estudos na linguagem C.